# VBA Create chart on filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am combining datasets from different sources in one Excel sheet and my aim is to automatically create a Chart. However, depending on the status of a Checkbox on the sheet the Chart should in both states only include a filtered set of the table.

To give you a better Impression, my table looks like this:
[image]

So when the box is checked, filter the data in column G build the Chart from the remaining rows. If unchecked, filter for other numbers etc.

The values in column S are calculated by a Formula. So Overall, my approach Looks like this:

```
Sub Analysis()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Clear worksheet data
ws.Range("A2:R" & CStr(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).Clear

'Copy data from source files to active sheet

Dim lngRows as long
lngRows = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'##########################################################################
'Apply filters according to checkbox on sheet
'If only supplier parts checked, filter according to column "Beschaffungsart"

'Has checkbox been checked to only regard parts from supplier?
Dim onlySupplierParts As Boolean
onlySupplierParts = CBool(ws.Cells(9, ColC2N("U")).Text = "WAHR")

If onlySupplierParts Then
    ws.Range("$A$1:$S$" & CStr(lngRows).AutoFilter Field:=1
    ws.Range("$A$1:$S$" & CStr(lngRows).AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="F"
Else
    'don't filter for supplier parts, only filter empty rows
    ws.Range("$A$1:$S$" & CStr(lngRows).AutoFilter Field:=17
    ws.Range("$A$1:$S$" & CStr(lngRows).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

    'ATTENTION: if not filtered for supplier parts, filter accordingly
    ws.Range("$A$1:$S$" & CStr(lngRows).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("101", "102", "103"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
'##########################################################################


'Sort retrieved data according to date column
[...]

'Apply sum formula to column S
Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]"
Range("S3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-7]"
Range("S3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S3:S" & CStr(Worksheets("Warenbewegungen").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Delete old chart
Dim chtobj As ChartObject
For Each chtobj In ws.ChartObjects
   chtobj.Delete
Next chtobj

'Add chart
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("B6:P70")
Set chtobj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng.Left, Width:=rng.Width, Top:=rng.Top, Height:=rng.Height)
chtobj.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
chtobj.Chart.HasTitle = True
chtobj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Verlauf Lagerbestand"

With chtobj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   .Name = "Progress over time"
   .Values = ws.Range("S2:S" & CStr(lngRows))
   .XValues = ws.Range("I2:I" & CStr(lngRows))
End With

End Sub
```

Now my problem is that the range included by the chart is not limited to the cells which are still visible after applying the filters.

I thought about saving the whole dataset in an array and filter it "manually", but I do have a feeling that this is incredibly inefficient. Research on the topic showed that there should be some kind of solution using xlSpecialCells, however it is not entirely clear to me how it would look like in this case :/

I am sure there is an elegant solution, I appreciate any hints.
Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

By default, a chart will not plot data in hidden rows of a table. Simply make the chart using all rows of the table, and when the table is filtered, some rows are hidden, and these rows are not plotted.